# kivymd buttons remain on the left of the screen

Tags: python, button, kivy, kivymd, boxlayout

I can't position my buttons in the center on kivymd, I tried first with a normal boxlayout and then the two buttons but they remain attached to each other, (I tried inserting two labels and they are positioned in the center without problems but with the buttons it's not like that) then I tried to make two layout boxes inside a layout box but one button was placed on the left (to the left of the first layout box which divides the page in half) and the other in the center (to the left of the second layout box ) how can I position them in the center?

kivy code:

```
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical" 
            BoxLayout: 
                orientation: "horizontal"
                BoxLayout:
                    
                    MDRectangleFlatButton:
                        halign: 'center'
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        text: "hi"
                       
                BoxLayout:
                    MDRectangleFlatButton:
                        text: "hi"
                        halign: 'center'
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal" 
            
    AnchorLayout:
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            text: "hi"
    AnchorLayout:
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "hi"
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

The `MDRectangleFlatButton` sets its `size_hint` to `[None, None]`, so it does not fill the available space. The `AnchorLayout` leaves the default `size_hint` of `[1, 1]`, so the two of them evenly share all the available space.

Comment: yes but I would like to have smaller buttons always in the center of the layout that do not take up the whole page, by doing this I could simply specify the size_hint and the buttons will be arranged equally but will take up the whole page, I don't know if you have understood what I want to do

Comment: Did you try my answer?